# How do I count many times a user responded something?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I find how many times a user said 'W'? What I am trying to do is

```
print("Enter 'W' if you won and 'L' if you lost.")
gameOne = input("First game     ")
gameTwo = input("Second game    ")
gameThree = input("Third game   ")
gameFour = input("Fourth game   ")
gameFive = input("Fifth game    ")
gameSix = input("Sixth game     ")
```

and then count how many times they said 'W' or 'L'.

Comment: Use a while loop and count within it.

Comment: @FatihAkici that is not necessary as there are built in functions that can avoid while loops (see LPython's answer)

Comment: prepare a tuple of all inputs i.e `(gameOne, ....)` then use the `count` method on that tuple i.e `all_input_tupe.count('W')`

Comment: @lbragile list.count method does apply a loop. A built-in method doesn't mean you are avoiding a loop.

Comment: @FaithAkici **while loop** not just any loop, of course it has to iterate through the items in the list/tuple somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this result by utilising count() over a list or tuple you combine the results in.

```
gameOne = 'W'
gameTwo = 'L'
gameThree = 'W'
gameFour = 'L'
gameFive = 'W'
gameSix = 'L'

results = (gameOne, gameTwo, gameThree, gameFour, gameFive, gameSix)
results
('W', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'L')
results.count('W')
3
results.count('L')
3
```

count(string) will return the number of times that string occurs within a list or tuple.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a list of the answers:

   `answers = [game_one, game_two, game_three, game_four, game_five, game_six]`
2. Count the number of times this list has 'W':

   `sum_w = len([i for i in answers if i == 'W'])`
3. Remainder of total list length and `sum_w` will give you the other sum:

   `sum_l = len(answers)-sum_w`

Note that I used `game_x` as my variables to adhere to Python coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of arrays and loops.

You can have two loops: the first will keep on asking you for user inputs. Store each user input into an array.

You can assign a specific input to end the loop that keeps asking the user for a new input.

Once the first loop is done, you can have a second loop, which iterates the input array. You can add logic there like, checking for a specific value of each input in the array, and then updating a counter variable, to later show using print.

Have these as references on how to use arrays and loops, and if-statements:

Arrays:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Loops:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

If-Statements:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

Edited....